# merlin package Error in merlin_error_check(model = model, data = data, timevar = timevar, : Outcome must be numeric

Tags: r, mixed-models

I have a long dataset of 495 obs of year, month, age-group, population, deaths, and death_rate.

```
> head(join_yearmonth,n=10)
# A tibble: 10 x 8
    year month agegp COUNT deaths   pop death_rate date     
   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <yearmon>
 1  2010 01    00-17     5      5 31506      190.  Jan 2010 
 2  2010 01    18-44    10     10 57818      208.  Jan 2010 
 3  2010 01    45-64    12     12 32804      439.  Jan 2010 
 4  2010 01    65+      30     30 12523     2875.  Jan 2010 
 5  2010 02    00-17     3      3 31506      114.  Feb 2010 
 6  2010 02    18-44     5      5 57818      104.  Feb 2010 
 7  2010 02    45-64    12     12 32804      439.  Feb 2010 
 8  2010 02    65+      34     34 12523     3258.  Feb 2010 
 9  2010 03    00-17     1      1 31506       38.1 Mar 2010 
10  2010 03    18-44     4      4 57818       83.0 Mar 2010
```

The two variables I'm attempting to use in the model below are both numeric:

```
> class(join_yearmonth$year)
[1] "numeric"
> class(join_yearmonth$deaths)
[1] "numeric"
```

I was originally trying to do a more complicated model but kept getting error message so I simplified it until I was just using the following:

```
> merlin(deaths ~ year,
+        family = "gaussian",
+        data = join_yearmonth)
Error in merlin_error_check(model = model, data = data, timevar = timevar,  : 
  Outcome must be numeric
>
```

I'm not sure what I can do here, or what "Outcome" refers to, because my outcome variable is numeric. I also tried passing the join_yearmonth tibble through as.data.frame(), but it didn't work and the merlin documentation says it should work on tibbles as well.

Comment: What do you mean by `as.data.frame` didn't work ? I try reproduce your code and it effectively doesn't work with the tibble but it seems ok when data is a data.frame

Comment: You're right. I tried to use data = as.data.frame(join_yearmonth) as an argument which did not work, but when I converted the tibble to a df and then passed it through the function, it worked.